Draw consecutive arrows without touching each other using Tikz?
I want to draw this shape but I don't know how to make the arrows not touch each other. Someone please help me?


welcome to TeX - would you like to share code of what you have tried so far to achieve the result - it helps avoiding start from scratch

The following MWE may serve as a starting point:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge/.style = {draw=blue, semithick, -Stealth,
                     shorten >=1.2pt, shorten <=1.2pt}
                        ]
\draw   (0,0) edge (0,1)
        (0,1) edge (1,0)
        (1,0) edge (2,0)
        (2,0) edge (1,1)
        (1,1) edge (0,2)
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}


You can determine all the coordinates by appropriately defining two loops or you can just specify them manually by extending the above MWE. You can change the distance between arrows by adjusting shorten >=...pt, shorten <=...pt.
For further help you first need to show us, what you try so far and explain where you get stuck in your efforts, i.e. what is actually the problem.

@cfr, thank you very much for editing my (terrible) English (in the first sentence).

You're welcome. It wasn't terrible at all. I just thought it could be a little bit clearer. (And I hoped you wouldn't mind.)
